# Trying to populate Java Pojo class with MongoDB collection and getting null

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo, mongo-java, mongo-collection

I am trying to populate the Java POJO class with the Mongo DB collection but getting null when trying to get data from the Pojo class

Here **CSVRow** is the **POJO class name**

**The class constructor**

```
MongoDatabase database;

MongoDbUtils() {
    String uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/?maxPoolSize=20&w=majority";

    //This registry is required for your Mongo document to POJO conversion
    ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(uri);
    CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build());
    CodecRegistry codecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), pojoCodecRegistry);
    MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
            .build();
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(clientSettings);
    database = mongoClient.getDatabase("StudyPriceDataTest");
}
```

**Function to retrieve data from POJO**

```
public MongoCollection<CsvRow> RetriveAllDocumentsInCSVRows(String collectionName) {
    System.out.println(collectionName);
    MongoCollection<CsvRow> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName, CsvRow.class);
    List<CsvRow> csvRows = collection.find(new Document(), CsvRow.class).into(new ArrayList<CsvRow>());
    for(CsvRow doc:csvRows) {
        System.out.println("vinsds="+doc.getVin()); **<-- here I am getting null**
    }
    return collection;
}
```

I tried with the code mentioned and I am expecting to get the data from the POJO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
 public List<CsvRow> RetriveAllDocumentsInCSVRows(String collectionName) {
    List<CsvRow> userList = new ArrayList<CsvRow>();
    List<CsvRow> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName, CsvRow.class).find().into(userList);
    // return all documents in the collection
    for (CsvRow u : userList) {
        System.out.println(u.getVin());
    }

    return collection;
}
```